# Liking media with signed headers using Instagram API on Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, http, instagram

I enabled "Enforce Signed Header" for my application on the Instagram Developers "Manage Clients" page, and I included "client_ips" in the client constructor as

```
client = Instagram.client(:access_token => session[:access_token], :client_ips => "127.0.0.1")
```

in order to call the API with the X-Insta-Forwarded-For signature. *I'm running the application on localhost.*
However, when I now try to like photos using `like_media(id)`, there is no error rendered but the photos do not get liked. If I uncheck the "Enforce Signed Header" option, like_media works fine.

Is anyone having similar problems?

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same problem. In order for the X-Insta-Forwarded_For header signature to be automatically included, you need to also provide your client_id and client_secret when initializing the client. You should be good to go once you do that.